# Java 11 web application deployed in Tomcat 8.5 cause this error at runtime Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Document

Tags: java, tomcat, java-11, classnotfoundexception

I struggled for a week, I try to run my web application WAR file in Apache Tomcat 8.5 with Java 11 but gives the above error.

Can any one gives a solution ?

```
22-Dec-2022 10:11:40.237 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webappssso\lm.war]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:757)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1016)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1903)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/lm]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Document
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309)
at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredMethods(Introspection.java:133)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadMethodsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:285)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:138)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:69)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:328)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:782)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5130)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Document
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1420)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1228)
... 23 more
```

Comment: Do you have a class named `Document` in the unnamed (default) package in your project? The unnamed package should really only be used for the smallest of tests and anything with a build system (and definitely every webapp) should avoid its use entirely! Put it into a package. I don't know if this will solve your problem (it might!), but it's the right thing to do irrespective of this problem.

Comment: @JoachimSauer good catch. Most likely the class never made it into the war file by the packager. Was looking at reasons to do with Java 11 not including the XML parsers which would have it miss javax.xml.Document but your hunch makes more sense